# How to use agda almost without data, only with postulates?

Tags: logic, agda

```
module sets where

postulate
     : Set
    _∈_ :  →  → Set
infix 50 _∈_

data _and_ : Set → Set → Set where
    _∧_ : (x y : Set) → x and y
infixl 40 _and_
infixl 40 _∧_

data _≡_ : Set → Set → Set where
    _eq_ : (a b : Set) → a → b and b → a → a ≡ b
infixr 30 _≡_
infixr 30 _eq_

postulate
    _==_ :  →  → Set
    ==-def : (x y z : ) → ((z ∈ x ≡ z ∈ y) ≡ x == y)
infixr 50 _==_

postulate
    eq_ax : (x y : ) → (x == y) → (z : ) → (x ∈ z ≡ y ∈ z)
    ∃ : (x : Set) → (z : x → Set) → Set
    ∃-def : (x : Set) → (y : x) → (z : x → Set) → (z y ≡ ∃ x z)
    pair_ax : (x y : ) → ∃  λ { z → x ∈ z and y ∈ z }
    ∪ :  → 
    ∪_def : (x y : ) → x ∈ ∪ y ≡ ∃  λ { z → x ∈ z and z ∈ y }
    _⊆_ :  →  → Set
    ⊆-def : (x y : ) → ((z : ) → z ∈ x → z ∈ y) ≡ x ⊆ y
infixl 50 _⊆_

first-proof : (x y : ) → x ⊆ y → (∪ x) ⊆ (∪ y)
first-proof x y z = {!!}
```

I am new to Agda. I try to find something that can verify my evidence. And so far Agda seems to be the best option (but still not enough convenient). I am implementing ZFC. And don't know, how to proof the last sentence.

I expect to proof without data, closest to the usual proof with quantifiers and connectives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module sets where

data _and_ : Set → Set → Set where
    _∧_ : {x y : Set} → x → y → x and y
infixl 40 _and_
infixl 40 _∧_

data _≡_ : Set → Set → Set where
    eq : {x y : Set} → (x → y) and (y → x) → x ≡ y
infixr 30 _≡_

straight : {x y : Set} → x ≡ y → x → y
straight (eq (z ∧ w)) = z

back : {x y : Set} → x ≡ y → y → x
back (eq (z ∧ w)) = w

data ∃ : {x : Set} → (z : x → Set) → Set where
    exists : {x : Set} → (y : x) → (z : x → Set) → z y → ∃ z

postulate
     : Set
    _∈_ :  →  → Set
infix 50 _∈_

postulate
    _==_ :  →  → Set
    ==-def : (x y z : ) → ((z ∈ x ≡ z ∈ y) ≡ x == y)
infixr 50 _==_

postulate
    eq_ax : (x y : ) → (x == y) → (z : ) → (x ∈ z ≡ y ∈ z)
    pair_ax : (x y : ) → ∃ λ { z → x ∈ z and y ∈ z }
    ∪ :  → 
    ∪-def : (x y : ) → (∃ λ { z → x ∈ z and z ∈ y }) ≡ x ∈ ∪ y
    _⊆_ :  →  → Set
    ⊆-def : (x y : ) → ((z : ) → z ∈ x → z ∈ y) ≡ x ⊆ y 
infixr 50 _⊆_
 
th-1 : (x y : ) → x ⊆ y → (∪ x) ⊆ (∪ y)
th-1 x y z = straight (⊆-def (∪ x) (∪ y)) λ w i → straight (∪-def w y) (lm-1 w (back (∪-def w x) i))
    where lm-1 : (a : ) → ∃ (λ { z → a ∈ z and z ∈ x }) → ∃ (λ { z → a ∈ z and z ∈ y })
          lm-1 a (exists b _ (c ∧ d)) = exists b (λ { z → a ∈ z and z ∈ y }) (c ∧ (back (⊆-def x y) z b d))
```

I was able to done this proof. I had to add one data more. Several data blocks were wrong - now they are right - partly because of it I couldn't proof. Now I see Agda more convenient - I began to understand it more. I also added two auxiliary functions: straight and back.

It's sad that the answers are hard to find on the topic of Agda(

-----edited------

It is possible sometimes to use only functions. For example

```
postulate
    _and_ : Set → Set → Set
    and-def : {x y : Set} → x → y → x and y
    right : {x y : Set} → x and y → y
    left : {x y : Set} → x and y → x
```

But, in the end, I came to use data. Functions don't allow to introduce parameters not in implication. For example we cannot write something like this

```
data ∃ : {x : Set} → (z : x → Set) → Set where
    c-∃ : {x : Set} → (y : x) → (z : x → Set) → z y → ∃ z
∃-element : {x : Set} → (z : x → Set) → ∃ z → (and-def (y : x) (z y))
```

It produces parse error at "y : x".